# Чтение данных из сокета в C#

Tags: c#, сокет, сеть

Как корректно и без костылей считать данные из сокета?  
 До этого писал на C++/Qt  и там был замечательный метод QTcpSocket::readAll() который возвращал все что было передано в сокет, в шарпе из подобного увидел только StreamReader.ReadToEnd(), но он выкидывает исключение мол этот объект не поддерживает seeking(или как-то так). 
 В гугле нашел только способы которые предлагают отлавливать окончание данных посредством try{}catch{}, но мне кажется это просто грубые кривые костыли. 
 В общем буду рад любой помощи по данному вопросу. 
 **P.S.:** А в Qt все было так просто, понятно и логично...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам правда надо прочесть всё, что пришло (это редко нужно, на самом деле), то вы можете использовать свойство [Socket.Available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.socket.available.aspx). Получив количество готовых байт вы можете выделить буффер нужного размера и прочесть всё, что готово.

В Java мне не раз приходилось работать с сокетами и я что-то не припомню, чтобы available мне хоть раз понадобился.. общая схема всегда одна и та же: делаю буффер и читаю в него, пока не закончится. Так что мне вообще не понятно, зачем вам read all.

Что же до try/catch - это действительно выглядит как костыль. Не ведитесь на такие советы.

Comment: Мне как раз нужно все. Я видел это свойство, но не понял как оно работает
<pre><code>TcpClient c = m_listener.AcceptTcpClient();
Console.WriteLine(c.Available);
NetworkStream ns = c.GetStream();
byte[] bytes = new byte[5];
ns.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
Console.WriteLine(c.Available);</code></pre>
В первом случае выводится 0, а во втором - сколько байт осталось. Можно конечно считать один байт, а потом остальное, но это опять похоже на костыль...
Socket s =...; s.Available тоже пишет 0... В примере из MSDN тоже выводятся нули...

Comment: Баг какой-то наверное. А может, не сразу обновляется как-нибудь.. может, толкьо после чтения обновляется. Да зачем вам это надо? Вы всё равно вынуждены будете обрабатывать поток по частям. Чтение до конца всегда очень условно: вы никогда не можете знать, а был ли конец или прилетит ещё пару байт (если, конечно, протокол вам точно не сообщает, или поток не закрылся).

Comment: Хм... Что-то не то с разметкой местной, отправлял все было красиво, а сейчас отображается коряво... Да, пожалуй верно, так и буду делать, но думал что есть что-нибудь вроде того же readAll()... А как же в таком случае узнать что поток действительно закончился?

Comment: Поймите, что смысла в readAll на нет. Это иллюзия, что вы читаете всё. На самом деле, нет разницы, читаете ли вы фиксированными блоками указанного вами размера или несколькими частями заранее неизвестного размера. Вам всё равно придётся обрабатывать поток по частям и никогда нет уверенности, что readAll прочёл именно **всё**

Comment: Или вы имеет в виду, что readAll читает всё до закрытия стрима? Но, вроде бы как документация такого не говорит..

Comment: Это вам повезло. Могу привести вам пример: предположим, что клиент посылает текст одной пачкой: "AAABBB", а на сервере говорят readAll. Пакет идёт идёт.. и вдруг случается какая-то хрень.. фрагментация какая-нибудь или ещё чего.. и.. пакет разрывает на два.. а второй отстаёт.. в результате readAll прочтёт вам "AAA".. а "BBB" придёт через пару миллисекунд.. чтобы прочесть и эту часть, вам бы надо вызывать readAll снова.. но тогда нет разницы, запрашивали ли вы конкретное количество байт (например, 512 байт) или спрашивали readAll